# javascript mouse event compatibility issue between browsers

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, cross-browser

I am new to the web development. I have a code that's supposed to change images when clicked on the image, and change the image back when released. And also it counts how many times it is clicked. I was building and testing this code on Safari and I didn't had any problems. It  works just as expected on Safari. However it does not work on Chrome and IE (I haven't tested any other browsers).

I was normally working with HTML5 Boilerplate however I reduced the code so that I can show here (This version doesn't work too).

I have given the code of the page below. What should I do to make it work on every browser. What is the reason that it acts differently on browsers?

Thanks in advance

```
<!html>
<html>
<head>

      <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;

    function incrementCount()
    {
        count++;
        document.getElementById( "count").innerHTML = count;

    }

    function pushTheButton()
    {
        document.images("bigRedButton").src = "img/pressed.gif";
        return true;
    }

    function releaseTheButton()
    {
        document.images("bigRedButton").src = "img/unpressed.gif";
        return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
      <div role="main">
        <p>
            <img src = "img/unpressed.gif" name="bigRedButton" onmousedown="pushTheButton()" onmouseup="releaseTheButton()" onclick="incrementCount()"/>
            </br>
            Click Count:<p id="count">0</p>
        </p>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I can make a suggestion, look into using jQuery. It has great cross browser support. When you use a framework like jQuery you can make one statement and don't have to worry about cross browser compatibility. jQuery is heavily tested for this issue.

Comment: actually I was using jquery. However it produced the same problem. I just shortened the code so that I can show here

Comment: I think I am wrong. I am not using JQuery code in this. However, even if its not query, i still wonder why it wasn't working in javascript.

Comment: @DaveThomas—far better for the OP to learn very basic javascript than load a 4,000 line library to support a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing in Chrome, remember to use its JavaScript console to watch for errors. In this case, it returns the following:

*Uncaught TypeError: Property 'images' of object # is not a function*

Your problem is on lines 18 and 24, when you attempt to access document.images("bigRedButton") -- document.images is an array (or possibly an object), not a function. It should be:

document.images["bigRedButton"].src

I don't know why it worked on Safari.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the problem.

Comment: For the record, [document.images](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) is an [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506), a type of [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177). They are similar to arrays in that they have a special *length* property and their members (arranged in DOM order) can be accessed by name, id or numeric index, but that's where the similarity ends. Both are live, meaning you don't have to get a new reference when they change.

Comment: By the way, I didn't even mention how to bring up Chrome's console. It's Ctrl+Shift+J.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp

document.images is documented a integer-indexed array of images.
To be really sure, you should use:

```
document.images[0].src = ...
```

Although accessing the image by using the name works in many cases as well.